# In the data explorer, how do you get the answers to a question?

Tags: support, questions, answers, data-explorer

Using [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), how can you find the answers to a particular question?

I would assume it would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT answers FROM (
    SELECT id=12345 FROM posts
)
```

However, there is no `answers` parameter in the schema.
How can I do this?

Comment: @BrockAdams omg syntax highlighting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

Both questions and answers are in the `Posts` table.

- Questions have a `PostTypeId` of 1
- Answers have a `PostTypeId` of 2
- If a post record is an answer, it will have a non-null `ParentId` that equals the `Posts.Id` of the parent question.

So, to get the answers to question number 2677, you would use SQL like:

```sql
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Posts a
WHERE   a.ParentId = 2677
```

For a more practical example, see this SEDE query:
        
[Anonymous Feedback for a specific question and its answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=2677)